# Nuxt is generating unwanted routes, when splitting .vue files. How do I get only the routes I want?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt project, I split up the `.vue` files in the pages directory to something like:

```
pages/
  index.vue
  shop/
    index.vue
    shop.js
    shop.pug
    shop.scss
  login/
    index.vue
    login.js
    login.pug
    login.scss
```

with the `shop/index.vue`, and `login/index.vue` src-ing their respective js/pug/scss files.

The routes for `/`, `/shop`, `/login` are working as expected, but I see that some other routes are also being generated: `/shop/shop`, and `/login/login` -- which are coming from the `shop.js` and `login.js` files I am assuming.

How do I prevent that? I just want it to use `index.vue`, or any `.vue` files for generating the routes.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Does answer work?

Comment: Hi, the `.nuxtignore` file does not seem to be working in my environment (Express server). But the ignorePrefix option as per your reference works. I would like to use something like `.nuxtignore`, I'll be opening an issue on Nuxt's github about this.

Edit: for now I'm using the `ignore` property for nuxt.config.js. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Put `.nuxtignore` file in your root.

File content:
`pages/**/*.js`

[Reference](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-ignore#-nuxtignore)